# WinDivert packet queue is causing disconnection

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, queue

I am passing received packets from WinDivert into a new Queue and using multi-threading to send/receive packets so that I can add time-stamps to the received packets, etc.

The problem seems to be that WinDivert stops sending packets to the Queue causing the network to eventually disconnect.

I have tried maxing out the WinDivert queue length / time and thread prioritisation along with recalculating missing checksums.

The problem can be reproduced by running 1-2 speedtests using speedtest.net while debugging the code.

WinDivert wrapper used: https://github.com/TechnikEmpire/DivertPInvoke

Comment: When you get an answer that isn't helping you, editing it is not the correct response.  Instead, downvote or flag and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Except that your edit did not improve the post in any way (it is 100% non-constructive and totally unrelated after the edit), and in fact it stands in the way of anyone educating that user about what is expected of them.  So don't do that.  Edits are for good answers that are hard to understand, if it isn't an answer in the first place, an edit can't help.

Comment: Who can tell what the intent of the original poster was, beyond that following the rules wasn't important to them?  Your edit was just as bad from a broken window perspective, and did nothing to help remove the answer more quickly.  Leaving a comment in reply to the answer is the correct way to make sure no one "takes the impression that it is ok to post" similar stuff.  Also, why do you persist on calling an answer a 'comment'?

Comment: Did you not see the difference in the way the site treats between the comments you and I are exchanging, for which there is no downvoting and no opportunity to suggest an edit, and the answer which jesuslvr posted?  It is considered an answer because it was posted using the "Post Your Answer" button.  It wasn't a real answer, but calling it a comment is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem can be reproduced by running 1-2 speedtests using speedtest.net while debugging the code.

Note that running some debuggers with WinDivert can cause a deadlock:
https://github.com/basil00/Divert/issues/26

Otherwise, yes it is possible to overwhelm a WinDivert application with enough traffic.  Diverting packets to and from a user application adds a lot of overhead.  If you really want to do this, then (1) run multiple threads, and (2) use non-blocking `WinDivertSendEx` to send packets without waiting for the result. See:
https://github.com/basil00/Divert/blob/master/examples/streamdump/streamdump.c

Comment: Executing outside of the debugger seems to have fixed the disconnection problem. Now it's just the overhead causing extremely high ping, as you can see in the example code provided I am using `WinDivertSendEx`, but I am not sure about creating multiple threads for this, do the threads need to be for both receive and send, and should I be using `WinDivertRecvEx`?

Comment: The design is application dependent, so it is up to you.  But in general, having N threads processing packets in parallel is better than 1.

Comment: I have tried using multiple threads, and it hasn't made much difference, I don't think it's the threads causing the problem. I have posted a new question regarding the latest errors I am having if you could take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136191/windivert-connection-loss