# WinDivert connection loss

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I am using WinDivert 1.1.8 MSVC x64 in Visual Studio 2015 along with a [P/Invoke wrapper](https://github.com/TechnikEmpire/DivertPInvoke/blob/master/WinDivert.cs) for C# to create a simple latency simulator, but the connection fails when performing bandwidth intensive tasks, such as a speedtest.

**Output**

[image: WinDivert errors]

> ERROR_IO_PENDING 997 (0x3E5) Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.
>
> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER 122 (0x7A) The data area passed to a system call is too small.

**Notes**

Possible deadlocking caused by x64 remote debugging?

Possibly overwhelming the WinDivert queue?

**Update**

I have tried parallel threading and this produced the same errors.

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, Environment.ProcessorCount), x => RunDiversion());
```

**Update 2**

After further testing the code the offending line may be:

`packet.CopyTo(newpacket.data, 0);`

**Update 3**

CPU Stack
[image: CPU Stack]
WinDivert queue possibly needs marshalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `WinDivertRecvEx` instead of `WinDivertRecv` to avoid overlapped I/O. Also, you're using `Queue<T>` on multithreaded app, which I believe you should use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead.

I think x64 debugger may cause problems too. I'm running the app without debugging and it works (CTRL+F5).

Working code: https://gist.github.com/fahminlb33/16f69460466eb07f88e7588a285fb4f8

Comment: Appears to work thanks. I'll perform more intensive tests soon. Should I max the windivert queue too?